# How to enable sde Reader in fme2014

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form

I have windows 7 64bit running ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 and fme 2014. On another server I have ArcSDE9.3. I want to create an SDE Reader in FME but am unsure about how to connect. At the moment SDE Geodatabases are not activated. Looking at this - 
[Link to FME Site](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Error_Unexpected_Behavior/SDE-Libraries-for-64-bit-FME-reading-64-bit-SDE)
 - I need to connect to various SDE dlls etc and set environment variables and install the sde SDK. Is this really the only way to be able to connect to sde with fme?

Comment: Yes this is the official way to support ArcGIS SDE using FME 2014 - the quickest way is to install ArcGIS Explorer and create a Folder with the SDE .dlls and set the env variables.

Comment: I think at 10.1 the sde files are automatically installed. Then in fme you direct connect like. sde:sqlserver:my-server\my-instance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's it I think. They are probably libraries we aren't able to distribute, or we don't want to because they could interfere with your existing setup. [This](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Error_Unexpected_Behavior/ArcSDE-formats-greyed-out-in-Formats-Gallery) is another good resource page for setting up the connection. I'm thinking that if you have ArcGIS installed already then it's most the environment variables that need setting.